# Populate cell based on content of adjacent cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm looking for a formula to update the content of a cell based on information from an adjacent cell in google sheets.

Please see the link to example doc below.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H8V2Y6r_ZfeX2L269gKS4SrKOhmmtMdIY-sTXF1W96o/edit?usp=sharing

In this example, I have a budget sheet and am trying to update a cost column to fetch info from a list below it. So as names are changes in the dropdown menu the cost column next to it would update as well. Drop down menu is non-essential but provides an easy way to switch out the people.

Hope that makes sense. Let me know if you can shed any light on a formula I could use to achieve this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

formula you are looking for is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(B10:B14, B22:C25, 2, 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Thats spot on.